# Display Text only on hover

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, hover

I'm working on a shiny app in which I only want to want textouput on hover or mouse over action

I tried adding an action button

UI:

```
fluidRow(box (title = p("Rates by Gender and Race", actionButton("titleBtId", "", icon=icon('question-circle'),class = "btn-xs", title = "Info"),textOutput("text_id"),hover=T), width = 15, status = 'primary', solidHeader = TRUE,tabPanel('',plotlyOutput("racegender",height = "100%"))%>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1")))
```

Server:

```
output$text_id <- renderText({
  paste0("hi")
})
```

I'm not sure how would I edit it to only display text on hover

Comment: Do you want the text as a pop-up box? Or do you want the text appearing someplace in the UI on hover?

Comment: @phalteman I want it as a pop-up box
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to modal popups, depending on what user experience you want, is to use tooltips from the [`shinyBS`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyBS/versions/0.61) package, which has functions for subtle but effective popups and tooltips. Here is an example of the different functionality of hovering or clicking, and putting the tooltips in the UI or in the server, with equivalent experience. Note that theoretically you could put a hover tooltip in the UI using `tipify()`, but for some reason this doesn't seem to be working with actionButtons though it continues to work for other input elements.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("ShinyBS tooltips"),
   actionButton("btn", "On hover"),
   tipify(actionButton("btn2", "On click"), "Hello again! This is a click-able pop-up", placement="bottom", trigger = "click")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  addTooltip(session=session,id="btn",title="Hello! This is a hover pop-up. You'll have to click to see the next one.")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using ModalDialog

UI

```
fluidRow(
box (title = p("Rates by Gender and Race",  tags$head(                                     tags$style(HTML('#titleBtId{background-color:black}'))), actionButton("titleBtId", "", icon=icon('question-circle'),class = "btn-xs", title = "Info"),hover=T), width = 15, status = 'primary', solidHeader = TRUE,                                     tabPanel('',plotlyOutput("racegender",height = "100%"))%>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1")))
```

Server:

```
  observeEvent(input$titleBtId, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Note",
      "This chart if independent of Date-range and Age-range selections",
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
  })
```

Comment: Modals are a good method. If you're looking for something more subtle, see my alternative answer.